# best way to convert date in English to French, nsdate, localization

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nslocale

My property `dob` of `Patient` object is `String` and currently storing `12-Jan-2017` and I want to convert it to French locale such as `12-Janv.-2017`.

Below are my steps:

Converting `12-Jan-2017` into `1954-09-07 04:00:00 UTC`

```
let dateFormatter        = NSDateFormatter()  
dateFormatter.locale     = NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy" 
let date                 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("12-Jan-2017") // now date is 1954-09-07 04:00:00 UTC
```

Next I have to set the `locale` of `dateFormatter` to `fr`

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier: "fr")
let frenchDate       = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!) // now it is 12-Janv.-2017
```

I dont think it is the best way to do a conversion. Are there any other efficient way for it. Any comments are welcomed.

Comment: That is exactly how it is done. What are you worried about?

Comment: @MartinR: only thing I concern is that it takes me 2 steps: `1. converting Jan to 1` then `2. convert 1 into Janv.`. I thought there should be the way directly to convert `Jan` to `Janv`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(NS)DateFormatter` has methods to convert a date to a string representation and vice versa. There is no (built-in) method to convert
from one date format directly to another format without intermediate
`(NS)Date`. So what you are doing is fine.

Some suggestions though:

- Use optional binding instead of forced unwrapping to avoid a crash
  at runtime if the input string is not in a valid format.
- Use `DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate:...)` to get the 
  date format string appropriate for the chosen locale.

Then your code would be (in Swift 3):

```
let inputDate = "12-Jan-2017"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: inputDate) {
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "dd-MMM-yyyy", options: 0, locale: dateFormatter.locale)

    let frenchDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(frenchDate) // 12 janv. 2017
} else {
    print("invalid input date")
}
```